# Using livevalidation.js to validate several forms, but only the first one works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

So, at the moment I'm trying to validate a form with around 60 courses, where the maximum grade number would be 20. So, any number above 20 would show an error message saying "That value is too high" or something. (Most strings are in spanish so sorry for that.)

Now, the issue being, only the first form is getting validated, the other ones aren't getting validated for some reason.

Here's the code for two of the forms, the first form (Trayecto Inicial) is getting validated, but the next form (Trayecto I) isn't:

```
<?php

if(isset($trayecto) && $trayecto == "Inicial")
    { ?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend><b>Trayecto Inicial</b></legend>
                <table>
                    <form name="<?php echo $trayecto; ?>" method="POST"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          action="operaciones/update.php" >
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Proyecto Nacional y Nueva Ciudadania:</label></td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name="pnync" id="pnync" maxlength="2" size="10" value="<?php if($issetnotas > 0){ echo $nota['pnync']; } ?>" onkeypress="return validar(event, 'num');">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Taller de Introduccion</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="talleri" id="talleri" maxlength="2" size="10" value="<?php if($issetnotas > 0){ echo $nota['talleri']; } ?>" onkeypress="return validar(event, 'num');">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Matematica Inicial</label></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="matini" id="matini" maxlength="2" size="10" value="<?php if($issetnotas > 0){ echo $nota['matini']; } ?>" onkeypress="return validar(event, 'num');">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Construccion Civil y Sociedad</label></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="ccys" id="ccys" maxlength="2" size="10" value="<?php if($issetnotas > 0){ echo $nota['ccys']; } ?>" onkeypress="return validar(event, 'num');">
                        </td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="trayecto" value="<?php echo $trayecto."-".$row['id_persona']; ?>" />
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </fieldset>

<?php }
    elseif (isset($trayecto) && $trayecto == "I")
            {  ?>

            <fieldset>
                <legend><strong>Trayecto I</strong></legend>
                <fieldset>
                  <table>
                        <form name="<?php echo $trayecto; ?>" method="POST"   action="operaciones/update.php" >
                        <tr>
                            <td><h3>Trimestre I</h3></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Tutorial de Proyecto I:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="tutopro1" id="tutopro1" maxlength="2" size="10" value="<?php if($issetnotas > 0){ echo $nota['tutopro1']; } ?>" onkeypress="return validar(event, 'num');">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Construccion de Documento</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="costdocu" id="constdocu"     maxlength="2" size="10" value="<?php if($issetnotas > 0){ echo $nota['costdocu']; } ?>" onkeypress="return validar(event, 'num');">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Matematica</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="matematica" id="matematica" maxlength="2" size="10" value="<?php if($issetnotas > 0){ echo $nota['matematica']; } ?>" onkeypress="return validar(event, 'num');">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Fisica Aplicada</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="fisicaapli" id="fisicaapli" maxlength="2" size="10" value="<?php if($issetnotas > 0){ echo $nota['fisicaapli']; } ?>" onkeypress="return validar(event, 'num');">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                            <td><br><h3>Trimestre II</h3></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Topografia</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="topografia" id="topografia" maxlength="2" size="10" value="<?php if($issetnotas > 0){ echo $nota['topografia']; } ?>" onkeypress="return validar(event, 'num');">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Expresion Grafica y Dibujo de Proyecto</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="egdp" id="egdp" maxlength="2" size="10" value="<?php if($issetnotas > 0){ echo $nota['egdp']; } ?>" onkeypress="return validar(event, 'num');">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Estructura Organizativa del Estado</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="eode" id="eode"maxlength="2" size="10" value="<?php if($issetnotas > 0){ echo $nota['eode']; } ?>" onkeypress="return validar(event, 'num');">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><br><h3>Trimestre III</h3></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Mecanica</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="mecanica" id="mecanica" maxlength="2" size="10" value="<?php if($issetnotas > 0){ echo $nota['mecanica']; } ?>" onkeypress="return validar(event, 'num');">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Geografia y Habitad</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="geohabitad" id="geohabitad" maxlength="2" size="10" value="<?php if($issetnotas > 0){ echo $nota['geohabitad']; } ?>" onkeypress="return validar(event, 'num');">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Quimica General</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="quimicagene" id="quimicagene" maxlength="2" size="10" value="<?php if($issetnotas > 0){ echo $nota['quimicagene']; } ?>" onkeypress="return validar(event, 'num');">
                            </td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="trayecto" value="<?php echo $trayecto."-".$row['id_persona']; ?>" />
                        </tr>
                    </table>
            </fieldset>
```

I'm using the following code for the validations:

(I realize this is horribly against the D.R.Y concept, I'm very new at programming and I don't have much knowledge about JS or jQuery so I wouldn't know how to deal with this in a better way yet, will have to study later.)

```
<script>
var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('pnync');
ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('talleri');
ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('matini');
ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('ccys');
ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

var ValidarCasc = new LiveValidation('tutopro1');
ValidarCasc.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('constdocu');
ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('matematica');
ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('fisicaapli');
ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('topografia');
ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('egdp');
ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('eode');
ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('mecanica');
ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('geohabitad');
ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('quimicagene');
ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you just give us the HTML please? I'm assuming you're question is regarding only the client side validation (I don't see any validation in your php).

Comment: It looks like you might have some basic HTML syntax errors including not closing tags (no </form>) and invalid tags (tags without >).

Comment: The HTML is fine, sorry I didn't add the entire code as it would be really long, since i'm using a framework for the HTML and it has a shitload of stuff but yeah they're closing and working with no issues, I posted an image below as how it looks.


There's no validations on the php side but I added the JS validations i'm using at the bottom part of the post, which is where I'm having those problems.

Comment: No, based on the php you have posted, I don't think your HTML is fine. I'm not asking for all of it, just the relevant part. Your php is obfuscating the problem. As far as the browser is concerned it's all HTML, and therefore when you're debugging things client side it's only the HTML that you should be looking at. Of course once you find the HTML/JS problem you may need to go back to the php to fix it, but starting from the php is just confusing when the problem is client side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your javascript is throwing exceptions for the fields that exist in form1 when your PHP code is set to show form2.

You need to wrap each set of validations (per form) in a test (the below code assumes you are using jquery, if not, write the appropriate javascript version of the test i'm doing)

```
if ($('#myFormName').length > 0) {
    var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('pnync');
    ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });

    // and so on for all fields that belong to "myFormName"
}
if ($('#myOtherFormName').length > 0) {
    // other form validations
}
```

or the other (less elegant) thing you can do is (no jquery needed here btw)

```
<script>
try {
    var ValidarNota = new LiveValidation('pnync');
    ValidarNota.add(Validate.Numericality, { minimum: 0, maximum: 20, onlyInteger: true });
} catch (e) {

}


and so on for each one
```

Comment: I don't know exactly how LiveValidation.js works, but as long as the developer doesn't need to access the variable anymore, writing over the reference shouldn't cause an error. That being said, it is very distracting.

Comment: I tried changing the variable name, didn't change anything though.

Comment: also, nested forms don't perform very well, and if both forms are somehow appearing on your page, you didn't </form> the first one before starting the second one.  I would still submit that theres no way both forms are appearing on your page at once though, as they are part of a related if/else statement, so only one will probably show up at a time.

Comment: This is how it currently looks, these fields get validated but when I press Trayecto I, the fields there won't get validated.

http://i.imgur.com/Iuh5ueP.png

Comment: i think i see the problem... only the first form works because you check the first forms values in the first few lines of validation code... the 2nd form is probably throwing an error on validation because the first few lines (that only work on the first form) are throwing an exception so the rest of the code isnt being run.  To test this, move the lines that validate the second form to the top of your validation and you should see the first form fail and the second form work.

Comment: You're right, thank you. I did that and now the second form is working, how would I go about fixing that though?

Comment: Sorry but which few lines are you referring to?